# Props updated without dispatching in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.2",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"

```
const items = this.props.cart.cartItems;
const index = items.indexOf(item1);
items.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({ finalPrice: 0 });
```

In this scenario, the props 'cartItems' is updated to variable 'items' without dispatching action.

Comment: Simply change the first line to `const items = { ...this.props.cart.cartItems };`. It should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are mutating an object property of an object which is copied from another one without doing a deep copy. So, when you mutate a nested property, it also changes the original object. Either you make a deep copy or change the objects without mutating them.

- Assigning one object into another one do not create a totally different object unless you do a deep copy. Both objects references point the same object.
- `splice` mutates the original array. Either use `slice` or some other methods like `filter`.

```js
const cart = {
  cartItems: [
    "foo", "bar", "baz"
  ],
}

console.log( "original one before update", cart.cartItems );

const index = cart.cartItems.indexOf("foo");
const items = cart.cartItems.filter( (_, i) => i !== index );

console.log( "original one after update", cart.cartItems );
console.log( "new items", items );
```